# xss vulnerability in fortify for xml

Tags: c#, fortify

I am creating SOAP request in C# and passing into a `WebRequest` in `StreamWriter`:

```
Streamwriter postWriter = new Streamwriter(request.GetRequestStream());
postWriter.Write(soapRequest);
```

Fortify is throwing error for this and asking to validate the before making the request.

How should we validate the soap request and fix this xss fortify issue?

Comment: You can't simply write out an incoming request. You need to encode it; how you do that depends on your application: Think HTMLEncode or URLEncode'd.  The reason you can't is that I can pass a malicious request in and you're happily accepting it. That's bad.

Comment: George I am creating the soap request in c# code, it does not have any user entered data. And I can't encode it as I am making request to some third-party application which is expecting data in xml format

Comment: Yogesh, you're accepting a WebRequest without validating anything about it. It doesn't matter *who* it's from.  You have to validate and encode that webrequest if you want your error to go away.

Comment: To be more direct; you need to strip off any headers you don't want to pass on, and the request body needs to be encoded; as do any url parameters (depending on the sort of request it is. We'd need to see an example output of the WebRequest to know).

Comment: Can't encode it as request expecting data in xml format.

Comment: Yogesh; you need to encode the actual data you're sending across; not the entire request. So, if you're sending an XML request, you need to make sure the tags are valid and expected XML, and that the data inside the XML is CDATA--'d and encoded

Comment: Ok will give that a try

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think @Yogesh is creating the `WebRequest` and then writing to its stream, not accepting the request. I'm getting this same warning for WebRequest where I have to write binary data to a request stream to upload an image.